# Error in Nifi: Could not write to StandardFlowfileRecord

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-nifi

I recently created a Nifi docker image to be able to run a nifi docker with my custom configuration and status.

Everything worked fine, but after a while I received the following error:

```
2019-04-08 10:42:26,107 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.c.r.StandardProcessSession Failed to commit session java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot update journal file ./flowfile_repository/journals/449486.journal because no header has been written yet.. Will roll back.
2019-04-08 10:42:26,108 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] d.f.fit.processors.opcua.GetOPCData GetOPCData[id=e8affa98-0169-1000-1717-d9e8f54293ea] GetOPCData[id=e8affa98-0169-1000-1717-d9e8f54293ea] failed to process session due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot update journal file ./flowfile_repository/journals/449486.journal because no header has been written yet.; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot update journal file ./flowfile_repository/journals/449486.journal because no header has been written yet.
    at org.apache.nifi.wali.LengthDelimitedJournal.update(LengthDelimitedJournal.java:230)
    at org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.update(SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.java:123)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.updateRepository(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:309)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.updateRepository(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:259)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:368)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:343)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:28)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot update journal file ./flowfile_repository/journals/449486.journal because no header has been written yet.
            at org.apache.nifi.wali.LengthDelimitedJournal.update(LengthDelimitedJournal.java:230)
            at org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.update(SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.java:123)
            at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.updateRepository(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:309)
            at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.updateRepository(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:259)
            at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.rollback(StandardProcessSession.java:1060)
            at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:501)
            ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Is it something to do with java heap or memory? How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Nifi docker with logs limits:

```
 docker run --name nifi -p 8080:8080 --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=5m --log-opt max-file=4  --restart always -d nifi
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was running out of open file handles, and unfortunately the error gives no indication of this. How I figured it was to:

Query the NiFi diagnostics. ex: 
`curl http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/system-diagnostics`

Check all the 'free' fields (ex. "provenanceRepositoryStorageUsage.freeSpace") and ensure you have enough resources.

For me this returned values like:

`flowFileRepositoryStorageUsage.totalSpaceBytes=-1`

-1 is reported when NiFi fails to determine these values. A proper error message will get logged as part of the diagnostics. You may need to check the logs quickly. In my case I had rolling logs setup so the log message quickly disappeared (so many processors were logging failures and filling up the logs). The error looked like:

```
2019-06-03 18:48:59,619 ERROR [pool-10-thread-1] org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Unable to checkpoint FlowFile Repository due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./flowfile_repository/journals/8243.journal (Too many open files)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./flowfile_repository/journals/8243.journal (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.\u003cinit\u003e(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.\u003cinit\u003e(FileOtutputStream.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.nifi.wali.LengthDelimitedJournal.getOutputStream(LengthDelimitedJournal.java:136)
    at org.apache.nifi.wali.LengthDelimitedJournal.writeHeader(LengthDelimitedJournal.java:151)
    at org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.checkpoint(SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.java:306)
    at org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.checkpoint(SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.java:251)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.checkpoint(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:735)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository$1.run(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:693)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The important part here is 'Too many open files'.

To get the current limits using linux: `ulimit -x -n`

To get the number of open files using linux: `sudo ls /proc/$NIFI_PID/fd | wc -l`

I'm using docker so I increased the limit with the docker run command: `docker run --ulimit nofile=1048576:1048576 ...`

Other solutions would be: increase the limits on the host machine, determine which processors are taking up the handles and re-work them (not so easy).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about any data in your flow, you can shutdown and remove all the "repository" directories, they are created in NiFi's home directory by default.

It doesn't explain what caused this in the first place, but it should get you back to a working state.

Comment: The problem is that every 2 hours this error occurs, so it is not a good idea to restart the docker every time it occurs.

Comment: any chance you are running out of disk space when this happens?

Comment: Could be. But I don't find any queues on my processor. How can I check which processor or task is full on my system?

Comment: I'm getting this all the time as well now, but only when running with docker in AWS. free inodes, disk space, permissions, ..., don't look like a problem. The only thing I've seen suspicious is NiFi diagnostics. (curl http://$(hostname -i):8281/nifi-api/system-diagnostics). I see: flowFileRepositoryStorageUsage.totalSpaceBytes=-1
Restart process within the container and it goes away but that is not a long term solution.